# how to get category name tablayout android rest api?

Tags: android

How to add json using Viewpager at load page.already use fragmentTablayout offline data. how to get json array select category name error [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XAia.png)  **   return (String) getResources().getString(Menu1.cid);  not get cid json    this tablayout how to set select category name how to slove this problem  rest [api](https://kalviaruvi.com/shopping/api/api.php?get_home&api_key=cda11Uib7PLEA8pjKehSVfY0vdHsXI269J3MlqcGatWZBmxOgR)

```
public class FragmentTabLayout extends Fragment {

    public RelativeLayout tab_background;
    public CustomTabLayout smartTabLayout;
    public ViewPager viewPager;
    public RtlViewPager viewPagerRTL;
    public int tab_count = 12;
    SharedPref sharedPref;
    View view;
    public List<shopmenu> shopmenu;
    public FragmentTabLayout() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (AppConfig.ENABLE_RTL_MODE) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_layout_rtl, container, false);
        } else {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_layout, container, false);
        }
        sharedPref = new SharedPref(getActivity());
        tab_background = view.findViewById(R.id.tab_background);
        smartTabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        if (sharedPref.getIsDarkTheme()) {
            tab_background.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorToolbarDark));
            smartTabLayout.setSelectedIndicatorColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccentDark));
        } else {
            tab_background.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        }
        initViewPager();
        return view;

    }

    public void initViewPager() {
        if (AppConfig.ENABLE_RTL_MODE) {
            viewPagerRTL = view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager_rtl);
            viewPagerRTL.setOffscreenPageLimit(tab_count);
            viewPagerRTL.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), tab_count));
            smartTabLayout.post(() -> smartTabLayout.setViewPager(viewPagerRTL));

        } else {
            viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
            viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(tab_count);
            viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), tab_count));
            smartTabLayout.post(() -> smartTabLayout.setViewPager(viewPager));
        }
    }

    public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        private final List <shopmenu > shopmenu = new ArrayList< >();

        int noOfItems;

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int noOfItems) {
            super(fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
            this.noOfItems = noOfItems;
        }



        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {


            if (position == 0) {
                return new FragmentHome();
            } else if (position == 1) {
                return new FragmentHome1();
            } else if (position == 2) {
                return new FragmentHome2();
            } else if (position == 3) {
                return new FragmentHome3();
            } else if (position == 4) {
                return new FragmentHome4();
            }else if (position == 5) {
                return new FragmentHome5();
            }else if (position == 6) {
                return new FragmentHome6();
            }else if (position == 7) {
                return new FragmentHome7();
            }else if (position == 8) {
                return new FragmentHome8();
            }else if (position == 9) {
                return new FragmentHome9();
            }else if (position == 10) {
                return new FragmentHome10();
            }else if (position == 11) {
                return new FragmentHome11();
            }else if (position == 12) {
                return new FragmentHome12();
            }

            else {
                return new FragmentHome();
            }
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return noOfItems;
        }

        @Override
        public String getPageTitle(int position) {
            if (position == 0) {

        com.Tnpsc.Group.models.shopmenu Menu1 = shopmenu.get(1);
        String categoryName = Menu1.category_name;

                return (String) getResources().getString(Menu1.category_name);
            } else if (position == 1) {
                return getResources().getString(R.string.title_nav_home);
            } else if (position == 2) {
                return getResources().getString(R.string.title_nav_home);
            } else if (position == 3) {
                return getResources().getString(R.string.title_nav_home);
            } else if (position == 4) {
                return getResources().getString(R.string.title_nav_home);
            }else if (position == 5) {
                return getResources().getString(R.string.title_nav_home);

            }else if (position == 6) {
                return getResources().getString(R.string.title_nav_home);

            }else if (position == 7) {
                return getResources().getString(R.string.title_nav_home);
            }else if (position == 8) {
                return getResources().getString(R.string.title_nav_home);
            }else if (position == 9) {
                return getResources().getString(R.string.title_nav_home);
            }else if (position == 10) {
                return getResources().getString(R.string.title_nav_home);
            }else if (position == 11) {
                return getResources().getString(R.string.title_nav_home);

            }else if (position == 12) {
                return getResources().getString(R.string.title_nav_home);
            }else {
                return getResources().getString(R.string.title_nav_home);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

> > `E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.Tnpsc.Group, PID: 31535 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437) at com.Tnpsc.Group.fragments.FragmentTabLayout$ViewPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(FragmentTabLayout.java:140) at com.Tnpsc.Group.fragments.FragmentTabLayout$ViewPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(FragmentTabLayout.java:79) at com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout.SmartTabLayout.populateTabStrip(SmartTabLayout.java:390) at com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout.SmartTabLayout.setViewPager(SmartTabLayout.java:328) at com.Tnpsc.Group.fragments.FragmentTabLayout.lambda$initViewPager$1$FragmentTabLayout(FragmentTabLayout.java:75) at com.Tnpsc.Group.fragments.FragmentTabLayout$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:2) at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)`

model

```
public class shopmenu implements Serializable {

    public int cid = -1;
    public String category_name;
    public String category_image;
    public String recipes_count;


}
```

Comment: Why `shopmenu.get(1)` every time? And the Exception already said it, the size is 0 and you try to get the item at position 1. Read the log and recheck your `shopmenu` data

Comment: @Tam Huynh
 return (String) getResources().getString(Menu1.category_name);   select data category name how to set

Comment: @Tam Huynh  this  tablayout

Comment: Forget about `Menu1.category_name` line, the crash happens above it from `shopmenu.get(1)` when `shopmenu` is empty. You should place a breakpoint and debug your code first

Comment: @Tam Huynh  code update bro how to get rest api shopmenu category name tablayout set

Comment: @Tam Huynh  recheck bro code update

Comment: Just search for Json reader in Java, place json file in assets and parse the data, pass it to the `Adapter`. I cannot help further if you haven't tried it

Comment: @Tam Huynh
json https://kalviaruvi.com/shopping/api/api.php?get_home&api_key=cda11Uib7PLEA8pjKehSVfY0vdHsXI269J3MlqcGatWZBmxOgR

Comment: @Tam Huynh   check bro api

Comment: Hi, as you are a newcomer to Stackoverflow, we will not help if you ask for a new feature without even trying any code to do it, we all have work to do. If you need to call API and parse json, then search for it on Google. I will give you some keywords for a better start: Retrofit and Gson

Comment: @Tam Huynh  i am new android devloper help me bro

Comment: @Tam Huynh  google search not get any answer bro